# What is the use of " const"?

Tags: c++, int, constants

Hi guys I'm new with C++, whats the difference between using `const int n=1` and `int n=1` , I dont understant what does `const` do. Can you give me examples or something?

Comment: What do you thinl it possibly mean?

Comment: The concrete example can be answered, but otherwise this question is far too broad. Can you limit it down to that example?

Comment: In the `const` case `n=42` const be compiled.

Comment: sorry if this is duplicated, its because im super new here, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

With `const int n=1`  you cannot modify the value of n in your code, for example if you try to do `n= 4` then it would cause an error, 
but with simple `int n=1;` you can always modify the value of n in your code like this

```
n= 4;
n=7;
```

Comment: Sorry if this is duplicated, I'm very new on stackoverflow.

Comment: ahhhhh thanks for the help Zia Qamar, I understand now!